# Difference between arithmetic vs geometric random walk

Tags: random-walk

I have read about [arithmetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22geometric%20random%20walk%22#q=%22arithmetic%20random%20walk%22) and [geometric](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22geometric%20random%20walk%22) random walks. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Take an arithmetic random walk. Exponentiate it. That's a geometric random walk. However, be careful, because some authors mean something quite different by the term *geometric random walk* (one example, assuming my quick glance didn't miss something important, is [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/papers/survey.pdf))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arithmetic random walks are modeled as *sums* of random *terms* while geometric random walks are modeled as *products* of random *factors*.

Two examples are Brownian Motion and Geometric Brownian Motion. Brownian Motion has independent, identically distributed increments while the geometric version has independent, identically distributed ratios between successive factors.